# React-table rerendering doesn't work when props are changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme) and would like to render the table with/without [subComponent](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/100k-rows-w-pivoting-sub-components) based on a prop passed from the parent element.

I tried to update state -- new array with `data` and `columns`, but the table doesn't re-render.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzlnv44v69)

**js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { makeData, Logo, Tips } from "./Utils";

// Import React Table
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

const data = [
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  },
  {
    a: "32,000.02938488",
    b: "0",
    c: "32,000.02938488",
    d: "55,000"
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    Header: "a",
    accessor: "a"
  },
  {
    Header: "b",
    accessor: "b"
  },
  {
    Header: "c",
    accessor: "c"
  },
  {
    Header: "d",
    accessor: "d"
  }
];

class Table extends React.Component {
  state = {
    columns: this.props.columns,
    data: this.props.data
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.expand !== this.props.expand) {
      console.log("update data");
      this.setState({
        columns: [...nextProps.columns],
        data: [...nextProps.data]
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.expand);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.expand ? (
          <ReactTable
            data={this.state.data}
            columns={this.state.columns}
            showPagination={false}
            defaultPageSize={data.length}
            resizable={false}
            SubComponent={row => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1>expanded state</h1>
                </div>
              );
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <ReactTable
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            showPagination={false}
            defaultPageSize={data.length}
            resizable={false}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    expand: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.setState({ expand: false });
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    const { expand } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Table columns={columns} data={data} expand={expand} />
        <br />
        <Tips />
        <Logo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: looks like a bug that once `SubComponent` is set it can never be unset (componentDidMount or constructor). I updated the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/8yyq5q8n19). Maybe you should file an issue [here](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues)

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwz9ywrx27) is a work around that will force react-table to unmount and remount when expanded changed.

Comment: @HMR Thank you. Maybe you can write your second comment as an answer and I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in the source you should be able to reset the SubComponent, you con't do it with setting it to undefined though (something to do with how props would not overwrite state if it's undefined in props).

Setting SubComponent to null or false will get the [desired results](https://codesandbox.io/s/8yyq5q8n19)

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("props:", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={this.props.data}
          columns={this.props.columns}
          showPagination={false}
          defaultPageSize={this.props.data.length}
          resizable={false}
          SubComponent={
            this.props.expand
              ? row => (
                  <div>
                    <h1>expanded state</h1>
                  </div>
                )
              : false
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use your code, but this sample doesn't work without `expandChanged` in parent element [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvwpvwzr55) I think I will keep this question opened and create new issue. Thanks

Comment: @Matt You can't set `SubComponent` property to undefined, you can set it to false or null `: false` instead of `: undefined` in the sandbox

Comment: @Matt Created an [issue](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/1182) for this since setting a prop to undefined should not have that prop sticking around. Found where this bug was caused in their code but not sure how/if the maintainers will "fix" it.